# lightest ubunto flavor for distance learning

Tags: xubuntu, kubuntu, lubuntu

with almost every school having distance learning and many of my friends and families looking to get either a new laptop or iPad just to use it for chrome & google classroom or MS-Teams app, I thought of doing and installfest for old laptops they have to make them faster to be used for this single use only.

I was wondering from your vast experience which flavor would do the job? I remember testing xubuntu in old days but being far from the recent developments maybe there is something else? for example lubuntu? or even lighter (chrome/firefox + Microsoft Teams app?)

Most of those old laptops run on low ram and CPU and never on SSD as you know (core 2 duo 2GB RAM or less)

I had an initiative to install regular Ubuntu on a thumbdrive and wanted to clone it for them, but flashdrives are super slow when they start using SWAP.

any recommendations is highly welcome even if it was flashdrive/external USB drive or any other crazy idea you might have :)

Thank you

Comment: The lightest desktop once booted and running, may not be the lightest the moment you starting loading apps that use *toolkits* (or libraries) not used by the desktop, as the result is two sets of libs/tks in memory that do the same thing. Yeah Xubuntu got heavier (just as MATE did) when it ported to GTK3, but that loss doesn't matter when using GTK3 apps. Lubuntu gives two choices (GTK2 or Qt5) but GTK2 apps are rare (outside of `gimp`). Firefox is GTK3 but I don't know/use the other apps...  Lightest Ubuntu *flavor* in my testing is Lubuntu... but no-one uses an OS without apps..

Comment: It may also be worth the effort to expand your search beyond Ubunto or official flavors. It used to be that Lubuntu was really light on resources, but that's not as true as it once was, unless you want to stick with 18.04. [Here](https://itsfoss.com/lightweight-linux-beginners/) is a list of lightweight distros, which does have some Ubuntu flavors in it.

Comment: respectfully, (i don't know what the market is like where you are but) If "new iPAD"s are in your budget, the a decent laptop for that same price or lower should be able to run any linux distro. I don't think I've ever paid over 300 for a laptop and worried about the "weight" of linux for lightweight tasks like school/work... So lightening the load should just be a bonus. I would aim for the highest RAM within budget... Also, I have never had a thumbdrive install behave long-term, always ends up with constant disk errors. I attributed it to frequent physical trauma.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 18.04 would work with these laptops, and is quite light. It would be supported till 2021. Even after that, it will be much safer to use it than Windows. You would still be able to use latest browsers with snap/flatpak.

The issue is that MS Teams is a bloatware. It alone consumes more than 1 GB of RAM. Recent versions of Chromium and Firefox also consume a lot of RAM.

However, as mentioned in the comments, you can look for [lighter distros](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023224/https://itsfoss.com/lightweight-linux-beginners/), which are not official flavors of Ubuntu.